# How to use Connection Events for RedisTemplate in Spring-Data-Redis?

Tags: spring-data-redis, lettuce

I defined RedisTemplate with LettuceConnectionFactory, but i have no idea to create Connection Events for example in https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/Connection-Events.

How to get RedisClient instance with RedisTemplate?

Answer (score 1):

To do that I override LettuceConnectionFactory and I put the ClientResources:

```
    DefaultClientResources clientResources = DefaultClientResources.create();
    clientResources.eventBus().get().subscribe(e -> System.out.println("event: " + e));

    LettuceClientConfiguration clientConfig = LettuceClientConfiguration
        .builder()
        .clientResources(clientResources)
        .build();
```